# Executing VACUUM FULL on postgresql db which is stopped/down

Tags: postgresql

I am attempting to restart a postgresql db which has stopped/is down and requires a `VACUUM`.

http://suwala.eu/blog/2010/10/09/how-to-vacuum-postgresql/

Following the above sequence of commands, I can't seem to get the last line to execute right.

```
$ postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/data YOUR_DATABASE_NAME < /tmp/fix.sql
```

This gives me an error that says

```
postgres: invalid argument: "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME"
Try "postgres --help" for more information.
```

Any idea why?

CLARIFICATION

The 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME' and the data directory I used on my server are the correct ones.

Comment: Tell me you didn't actually put `YOUR_DATABASE_NAME` lol

Comment: Of course not :-) my own db name of course!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with desaster recovery, but shouldn't the sql file be piped into `psql` (after a --single startup that is). Btw: why did you turn off autovacuum? This should never be done (that's the only reason I can think of that any modern version would require this recovery)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be an issue in PostgreSQL, as according to documentation for [9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-postgres.html) and [8.3](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-postgres.html) it should work with those versions but doesn't.

However, using --single switch makes it work:

```
postgres --single -D [path-to-data-dir] [db-name] < /tmp/fix.sql
```

Comment: This I did too. I am generally familiar with the basics of PostgreSQL admin.

Comment: Do you get the same error with "postgres -D [path-to-data-dir] [db-name]"?

Comment: Yes. I get exactly the same error even if I do not do `< /tmp/fix.sql`

Comment: OK, last question - did you try it with --single option?

Comment: Thanks! `--single` seems to work. (haven't run the `< /tmp/fix.sql` yet.

Answer (score 8):

The referenced "how-to-vacuum-postgresql" page referenced in the question gives some very bad advice when it recommends `VACUUM FULL`.  All that is needed is a full-database vacuum, which is simply a `VACUUM` run as the database superuser against the entire database (i.e., you don't specify any table name).

A `VACUUM FULL` works differently based on the version, but it eliminates all space within the heap files which is held by the database for quick re-use, and releases it to the OS.  This can be much slower than the minimum needed to get back to a usable database, by orders of magnitude.  And since any inserts or updates after the `VACUUM FULL` require OS calls to re-allocate space to the database, it can cause slower execution afterward, unless your database had a lot of bloat.  (Although, if you turned off autovacuum, it might be in horrible shape, but you probably want to get back on your feet first, and sort that out later.)

Another issue with `VACUUM FULL` before version 9.0 is that while it eliminates bloat in a table's heap files, it tends to *increase* bloat in its index files, sometimes dramatically.  If you issue a `VACUUM FULL`, you should normally follow it with a `REINDEX` to get the indexes back into good shape.

The page referenced in the question also fails to heed the advice given in the PostgreSQL docs at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND to use single-user mode:

> since the system will not execute commands once it has gone into the
>   safety shutdown mode, the only way to do this is to stop the server
>   and use a single-user backend to execute VACUUM. The shutdown mode is
>   not enforced by a single-user backend. See the postgres reference page
>   for details about using a single-user backend.

As others have mentioned -- there is almost no use case where turning off autovacuum is beneficial.  It may be useful to *supplement* the autovacuum activity with explicit vacuums on large tables, or you may want to adjust autovacuum configuration, but really -- don't turn it off or you will see bloat which saps performance and you'll run into transaction ID wraparound problems periodically.  People who notice a performance hit when autovacuum is performing maintenance sometimes have an instinct to make it less aggressive in triggering, but that is usually counter-productive.  It is generally better to adjust the autovacuum cost limitation parameters to pace the work, rather than have it neglect tables which need maintenance.

Comment: wow. this is an amazingly detailed and comprehensive answer.

Thanks a lot for the elaboration, @kgrittn!